# Failed Permission Check error in Glassfish

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-5

I have a glassfish server set up to host an api for an android application. When I use the application, everything works great, but when my client uses the application, he claims that it crashes when he tries to log in. I don't have access to his phone, so I can't tell exactly whats going on. All I have to go on is this error I got from the logs:

```
JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(odmorite/odmorite)- permission(("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/api/signin" "POST"))
```

I gave him the latest debug apk, so assuming that he installed it correctly, we should have the same version. That error also pops up for other paths the app tries to access at his end. Has anyone had any experience with this error, and is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Assuming that the underlying JACC provider does what it's supposed to do, a denied `WebUserDataPermission` indicates that a Servlet `<user-data-constraint>` was violated; e.g. when a client attempts to connect over plain HTTP to an endpoint configured to only accept HTTPS connections. Refer to 3.1.3.2 of the [spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=115) for the specifics.

Comment: @Uux I did what was written in Navin's answer for question #22382585 in order to redirect http requests to https. The thing is, most people could normally use the website and the api. The error was present only for one person, and someone who tried to access robots.txt (I'm guessing google). I solved it by switching JACC from default to simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching JACC from default to simple. That solved the problem. If I run into the same problem in the future on another project, I will try to clean the generated directory as Tobi suggested, and I will update this question with the results.

Answer (score 2):

You might try following:

- stop glassfish server
- clean the [glassfishHomeDir]\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated directory
- start glassfish

Comment: It fixed the problem ! Thanks